# MouseDown Event and Progress Bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, mousedown

I would like to have a progress bar, where the value of the bar would rise if the button was being pressed down(MouseDown Event), the bar needs to rise simultaneousely.

Any ideas? I tried with a timer but this is all I have currently

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            progressBar1.UseWaitCursor = true;
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
        public void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();

        }
        public void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();  
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, have the progress bar keep incrementing while the user keeps the mouse button pressed down?

Comment: Exactly! The progress bar should keep adding value as long as the button is being pressed, I imagine, this would be best used with threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  progressBar1.PerformStep();      
}

void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  timer.Start();
}

void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Great job! Nice and Clean

Answer (score 1):

The following program will update the progress bar each 20 ms the mouse is held down and get 10 100% after 2 seconds

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Timer pbTimer;
    private int pbProgress = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pbTimer = new Timer();
        pbTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ProgressUpdate);
        pbTimer.Interval = 20;
        this.MouseDown += Form1_MouseDown;
        this.MouseUp += Form1_MouseUp;
    }

    private void ProgressUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pbProgress < 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = ++pbProgress;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pbTimer.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pbTimer.Stop();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        pbProgress = 0;
    }
```

Comment: It was tagged WinForms.

Comment: @LarsTech: Thanks. Just noticed that.

Comment: Great job mate, picked top answer since it was less code and more clean. Cheers!

Comment: @LarsTech: Updated for WinForms